# Facebook connection in IPhone app

Tags: ios4

```
 Some body give me and idea.
```

I am creating a simple app there i invoke the facebook by using FBConnection.

I used the method at time of load a facebook dialog method.

now my rerqrement is that i did not want to used this dialog box there i am entring user name and password . i want simple textfield that i create for user name and password. and one buttion i have created i need once i enter the user name and password from my textfield that i have created by nib. and once i click login buttion (its also i have created by Nib.)its get loging to face book without appering the dialog box login field.

Thanks
jay
9032595685

Answer (score 1):

Facebook uses OAuth, so you cannot avoid the Facebook Dialog where the user must grant his rights.
You can still create your own login form and sent the data to Facebook by Hand, but the OAuth Dialog will always be there.

Edit:

Read this: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/